# 二次元配列リストの個々の要素についての疑問

Tags: python

python初心者・独学者です。
本日、初めての質問をして、すっきり解決したのですが、その回答から新たな疑問が生じてしまったので、質問です。

```
list_a = [
    { "a" : "住所A" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "女" , "d" : "いる" } ,
    { "a" : "住所B" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる" } , 
    { "a" : "住所C" , "b" : "小児" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる"} ,
    { "a" : "住所D" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いない"} ]
```

のような二次元配列のリストがあり、`"b" == "小児"`の場合には、その行のリストすべてを削除して以下の`list_b`

```
list_b = [
    { "a" : "住所A" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "女" , "d" : "いる" } ,
    { "a" : "住所B" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いる" } , 
    { "a" : "住所D" , "b" : "成人" , "c" : "男" , "d" : "いない"} ]
```

を作成する場合、リスト内包表記を用いて、

```
list_b = [x for x in list_a if x["b"] != "小児"]
```

とすれば良いことは分かりました。

ここで、上記内包表記の記述方法に疑問がわきました。
list_aの中の特定の要素を記述する場合、例えば、

```
list_a[0]["b"]
```

のようにすると

```
"成人"
```

が帰ってきます。しかし、上記のリスト内包表記では、この`["b"]`の要素を指定するのに`list_a["b"]`のみで指定できています。`["b"]`の前の`[]`がないことに違和感があります。
例えば、

```
print(list_a[0]["b"])
```

は問題ありませんが、

```
print(list_a["b"])
```

ではTypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not strが帰ってきます。

この違いはどのように考えれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リストそのものと、リストの要素とを区別してください。リスト内包表記で使う変数はリストそのものではなく、リストの要素です。

質問文にあるのは dict のリストですが、もっと簡単なリストで考えると分かりやすいかなと思います。次のサンプルは、整数のリストの要素を全て +1 するものです。ここで `x` は `lst1` の各要素 `2`, `3`, `5`, `7`, `11` を順番に表します。

```
>>> lst1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
>>> lst2 = [x + 1 for x in lst1]
>>> print(lst2)
[3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
```

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、御返答ありがとうございます。なるほど、リスト内包表記で使用する変数は「リストの要素」なのですね。つまりlst1の例でみると、1行目のlst1=[ ]の「lst1」（①）と、2行目の内包表記の「lst1」（②）は意味が異なると言うことですね。

Comment: @MuneNiku  さん、いえ、内包表記の中の `lst1` は1行目の `lst1` と全く同じです。`x in lst1` と書くことで「`lst1` の要素 `x`」と書いているとイメージすると分かりやすいです。

Comment: なるほど、「lst1の要素x」という意味で、「x」はlst1の要素のインデックス（0,1,2,3,4）を順に参照していくということですね。イメージとしては　「x in lst1」という表記は、lst1[x]　と同値、といった感じでしょうか。

Comment: @MuneNiku さん、インデックスではなく要素そのものですね。あくまでイメージですが `x = lst1[0]`、`x = lst[1]`、……、といった感じです。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、御返答ありがとうございます。大丈夫です。あくまでイメージですが、x = lst1[0]、x = lst[1]、……、といった感じ、すごくわかりやすいです。